# Porque o WebBrowser não mostra reCaptchas?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet, recaptcha

Coloquei pra navegar normalmente nesse site. Porém ele além de deformar as Textbox do site, ele ainda não exibe os reCaptchas. O site da ScriptErros. Porém outros sites também dão, mas não fica igual isso.
O que pode ser?

FORM

[image: FORM]

CHROME

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: está relacionado com a versão do IE, da uma olhada aqui: https://www.cyotek.com/blog/configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-internet-explorer-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir a versão do Webbrowser para 11, para isso implemente a o método abaixo no seu form principal:

> Não esqueça do `using Microsoft.Win32;`

```
    public void VerifyVersion(WebBrowser webbrowser)
    {
        string appName = "";
        try
        {
            appName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

            RegistryKey fbeKey = null;
            ////For 64 bit Machine 
            fbeKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
            if (fbeKey == null)
                fbeKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
            using (fbeKey)
            {
                fbeKey.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }


            //For 32 bit Machine 
            fbeKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
            if (fbeKey == null)
                fbeKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
            using (fbeKey)
            {
                fbeKey.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(appName + "\n" + ex.ToString(), "Unexpected error setting browser mode!");
        }
    }
```

Modo de uso:

```
VerifyVersion(webbrowser1);
```

---

**No seu caso**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Fast_Bitcoin
{
    public partial class freeBitcoinForm : Form
    {
        public freeBitcoinForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            VerifyVersion(webbrowser1);
        }

        private void freeBitcoinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void VerifyVersion(WebBrowser webbrowser)
        {
            string appName = "";
            try
            {
                appName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

                RegistryKey fbeKey = null;
                ////For 64 bit Machine 
                fbeKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
                if (fbeKey == null)
                    fbeKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
                using (fbeKey)
                {
                    fbeKey.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }


                //For 32 bit Machine 
                fbeKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
                if (fbeKey == null)
                    fbeKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
                using (fbeKey)
                {
                    fbeKey.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(appName + "\n" + ex.ToString(), "Unexpected error setting browser mode!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Explicação:

Você precisa alterar o registro do windows para que o seu sistema entenda que o seu webbrowser tem que executar na versão 11.

Você tem que alterar o registro `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

```
fbeKey.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Acima estamos definindo a versão para 11, se quisermos outras versão segue a tabela a abaixo

```
Versão do IE    | Número para registro
    7           |   7000
    8           |   8000
    8 Standards |   8888
    9           |   9000
    9 Standards |   9999
    10          |  10000
    10 Standards|  10001
    11          |  11000
    11 Edge     |  11001
```